# How to rewriting url with .htaccess from a to b

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, directory, rename

I want this url https://www.example.com/aaa/... in my website
can rename to https://www.example.com/bbb/... by .htaccess
bbb is just a name, not folder that exists
How to do this?

Comment: This question has very low quality. Refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for further information and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "rename" here? Try to explain what you actually want to do, not how you think you might be able to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Try this rewrite in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aaa\/(.*)$ /bbb/$1 [R=301,L]
```